# I want to fetch details using social media plugin in my wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress website in which I want to embed social media plugin to register. What I need is to fetch some of their data when they use social media link and fill some of my fields with that data. Basically I want some fields auto filled when they register through social media.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jquery so the tag should be removed otherwise here is a link that will help you with that.

The user basically uses facebook, google, twitter, etc. to log in into your website and it will authenticate them.

https://support.knack.com/hc/en-us/articles/231796207-Single-Sign-On-with-Google-Facebook-Twitter-and-Custom